# Table captions not showing up when rendering Quarto to Word docx

Tags: r, quarto, gt

I'm writing a manuscript using Quarto and rendering to Word for collaborators to review. I'm using the gt package to generate some tables and I'm noticing that table captions don't appear to be working (while figure captions work fine). How do you get table captions to show up? Here is a reprex:

````
---
title: "test"
format: docx
---
```{r}
library(gt)
gt(mtcars) |>
  tab_caption("This is a caption")
```

```{r}
#| tbl-cap: This is also a caption
library(gt)
gt(mtcars) 
```
````

Comment: It worked in gt 0.7.0, but stopped working in 0.8.0 https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/1140 Untitil it is fixed (likely in 0.10.0), you can reinstall 0.7.0 with `pak::pak("rstudio/gt@v0.7.0")`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @olivroy, I thought this issue is solved after [seeing this issue closed](https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/1141).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `tab_header(title=...)`.

````
---
title: "test"
format: docx
---

```{r}
library(gt)
gt(head(mtcars)) |>
  tab_header(title = "This is a caption")
```
````